# which one should I used in order to check the uniqueness of enum values in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have an enum in Python, which I want to make sure that its values are unique. I see that there are 2 ways I can use to achieve it:

- Wrapping the class with `@verify(UNIQUE)`
- Wrapping the class with `@unique`

What is the difference with using each one of them? Which one should I use to gain the best performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use which ever you prefer. In terms of implementation the both are the same and I mean the same, its literally copy pasted code in enum.py in in the cpython repo.
This [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5dc8c84d397110f9edfa56793ad8887b1f176d79/Lib/enum.py#L1916C1-L1926C58) is for the `@verify(Unique)` and [this one](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5dc8c84d397110f9edfa56793ad8887b1f176d79/Lib/enum.py#L1636) for the `@unique`.

I would suggest to use `@verify` if you have other checks as well but if you only want to check for unique it would be better to use `@unique` since it will only reference the code needed.

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct.

The [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module provides the `@unique` decorator to maintain and fulfill uniqueness:

> A class decorator specifically for enumerations. It searches an enumeration’s [**members**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.EnumType.__members__)

whereas [EnumCheck](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.EnumCheck)'s has the decorator of `@verify(UNIQUE)` having the same purpose.

Since these class decorators merely check for the values not to repeat, like in the case of

```
@unique
class Days(Enum): 
    MONDAY = 1
    TUESDAY = 2
    WEDNESDAY = 3
    THURSDAY = 2 # ValueError: duplicate values found in <enum 'Days'>: THURSDAY -> TUESDAY
```

and you only have a finite number of elements, any possible differences in performance would most probably be negligable and what's true for a Python version may be false in the next, so I would not be too worried if I were you about the performance of this specific feature.

But, if you are still curious, then you can generate two huge Python files with 1000 enums each having 10000 values. If you evaluate their performance separately and they differ only in the decorator, then you can make a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

`@unique` is the specific form of `@verify`.

If you pass uniqueness constraint to `@verify` (`@verify(UNIQUE)`) , they would do the same thing. `@verify` can get more than one constraints like `CONTINUOUS` and etc.

As `@verify` can get multiple constraints, it loops though them and apply the constraint. So if you only need to check uniqueness I would suggest `@unique` because it will save from [this check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5dc8c84d397110f9edfa56793ad8887b1f176d79/Lib/enum.py#L1916). It will save 0.0000...1 second.